# Is there a rapid way in Python to Group by a column and lines to split?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a quick question. I want to import a .cvs file, and then i want to export it back. But in some cells there are more informations separated by \n. I manage to separete it but, i want to know is there a more faster way to do it? And after i finish with the data, i want to export it back, with the \n. I know is a bit confusing, i will put the example:

From This .csv read

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asd\nfgd | 11\n22 | Sys1 |
| mada\nchaca\nhera | 32\n120\n35 | Sys2 |
| yay | 344 | Sys3 |

to this

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asd | 11 | Sys1 |
| fgd | 22 | Sys1 |
| mada | 32 | Sys2 |
| chaca | 120 | Sys2 |
| hera | 35 | Sys2 |
| yay | 344 | Sys3 |

and vice-versa.

This is my code ( i did it only one way):

```
import pandas as pd

tabel=pd.read_csv('Test1.csv')

print(tabel)

Column1=[]
Column2=[]
Column3=[]
for i in range(0,len(tabel.index)):
    sys_n=[tabel.iloc[i, 2]]
    if "\n" in tabel.iloc[i,0] and "\n" in tabel.iloc[i,1]:
        Column1.append(tabel.iloc[i, 0].splitlines())
        Column2.append(tabel.iloc[i, 1].splitlines())
        nr_sys=len(tabel.iloc[i, 0].splitlines())
        Column3.extend([sys_n]*nr_sys)
    else:
        Column1.append(tabel.iloc[i, 0].splitlines())
        Column2.append(tabel.iloc[i, 1].splitlines())
        Column3.extend([sys_n])

print(Column1)
result=sum(Column1,[])
result1=sum(Column2,[])
result3=sum(Column3,[])
tabel2=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(result,result1,result3)), columns=[['Column1','Column2','Column3']])
print(tabel2)

tabel2.to_csv('Test1_1.csv',index=False)
```

Note: If Column1 has 2 lines, Column2 will have it too.

Comment: You can use `replace("\n", "")`. This will remove the `\n` from the string you're giving. If you want to put them back, you should write in a dictionary each position you eliminated the "\n". For this you can use `if "\n" in yourString` and this way you can get the column and the row where it occurrs, but you'll need the position in string also. For this you can use `yourString.find("\n")`, this will return the position where `\n` was found in the field you're examinating. At the end you can store in a dict like this: `{column: [row, positionInString]}` and use this dict to put them back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `tabel`

```
             Column1      Column2 Column3
0           asd\nfgd       11\n22    Sys1
1  mada\nchaca\nhera  32\n120\n35    Sys2
2                yay          344    Sys3
```

you could do

```
tabel2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Column1": c_1, "Column2": c_2, "Column3": c_3}
    for col_1, col_2, c_3 in tabel.itertuples(index=False)
    for c_1, c_2 in zip(col_1.split("\n"), col_2.split("\n"))
)
```

or

```
tabel2 = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        [c_1, c_2, c_3]
        for col_1, col_2, c_3 in tabel.itertuples(index=False)
        for c_1, c_2 in zip(col_1.split("\n"), col_2.split("\n"))
    ),
    columns=tabel.columns
)
```

Result:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     asd      11    Sys1
1     fgd      22    Sys1
2    mada      32    Sys2
3   chaca     120    Sys2
4    hera      35    Sys2
5     yay     344    Sys3
```

Given `tabel2` you could do

```
col_1, col_2, col_3 = tabel2.columns
tabel = tabel2.groupby(col_3, as_index=False).agg(
    {col_1: "\n".join, col_2: "\n".join, col_3: "first"}
)
```

Result:

```
             Column1      Column2 Column3
0           asd\nfgd       11\n22    Sys1
1  mada\nchaca\nhera  32\n120\n35    Sys2
2                yay          344    Sys3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every cell of each row has the same number of `'\n'` characters, you can split each cell on `'\n'` into a list using `Series.str.split`. Then, explode each list into a different row using `Series.explode`. You can apply that logic to every column using `Series.apply`.

**Expanding**

```
>>> df

             Column1      Column2 Column3
0           asd\nfgd       11\n22    Sys1
1  mada\nchaca\nhera  32\n120\n35    Sys2
2                yay          344    Sys3

>>> long = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.split(r'\\n').explode())
>>> long

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     asd      11    Sys1
0     fgd      22    Sys1
1    mada      32    Sys2
1   chaca     120    Sys2
1    hera      35    Sys2
2     yay     344    Sys3
```

**Compressing**

To invert the process you can group the rows by their index (`level=0`)  and concatenate string groups using `str.join`

```
>>> short = long.groupby(level=0).agg(r'\n'.join)
>>> short 

             Column1      Column2           Column3
0           asd\nfgd       11\n22        Sys1\nSys1
1  mada\nchaca\nhera  32\n120\n35  Sys2\nSys2\nSys2
2                yay          344              Sys3
```